# How to add environment variable 'DOTNET_CLI_HOME' to .Net Systemd service?

Tags: .net, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am installing Worker Service in VM's Ubuntu 18. When I am using below command getting error

```
sudo systemctl start myservice.service
```

Error:

```
 ● myservice.service - dummyservice in .NET Loaded: loaded
 (/lib/systemd/system/myservice.service; disabled; vendor preset:
 enabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-05-26
 23:53:20 IST; 10min ago Process: 3634 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet
 /home/linux/bin/Downloads/myservice.dll (code=exited,
 status=1/FAILURE)

 May 26 23:53:19 arvind systemd[1]: Starting myservice in .NET... May
 26 23:53:20 arvind dotnet[3634]: The user's home directory could not
 be determined. Set the 'DOTNET_CLI_HOME' environment variable to spec
 May 26 23:53:20 arvind systemd[1]: myservice.service: Control process
 exited, code=exited status=1 May 26 23:53:20 arvind systemd[1]:
 myservice.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. May 26 23:53:20
 arvind systemd[1]: Failed to start myservice in .NET.
```

This is my .service file

```
[Unit]
Description=my Service in .NET
# Requires=xyz.service
# After=xyz.service

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet  /home/linux/Downloads/myService.dll

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have added `DOTNET_CLI_HOME` to `.service` file

```
Environment=DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/temp
```

Now that file looks like it

```
[Unit]
Description=my Service in .NET
# Requires=xyz.service
# After=xyz.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet  /home/linux/Downloads/myService.dll
Environment=DOTNET_CLI_HOME=/temp
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: I think you mean `/tmp/`.

Comment: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/temp/.dotnet' is denied  (on ubuntu image)